# Using dotnet build project occurred value cannot be null error

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, dotnetnuke

I use following command build project Ryujinx: https:github.com/Ryujinx/Ryujinx.git

```bash
dotnet build -c Release -o build
```

The compilation process is all normal, I misused ctrl+c and interrupted the compilation. It gets following errors when I use the same command build.

Then I clean NuGet cache and run `build clean`, but useless. The same errors occurred when I build project.

How to solve this problem?

````bash
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Horizon.Generators\Ryujinx.Horizon.Generators.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Input\Ryujinx.Input.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Tests.Memory\Ryujinx.Tests.Memory.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Input.SDL2\Ryujinx.Input.SDL2.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.HLE\Ryujinx.HLE.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Audio.Backends.OpenAL\Ryujinx.Audio.Backends.OpenAL.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Graphics.GAL\Ryujinx.Graphics.GAL.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Graphics.Nvdec.Vp9\Ryujinx.Graphics.Nvdec.Vp9.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Cpu\Ryujinx.Cpu.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Tests.Unicorn\Ryujinx.Tests.Unicorn.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Audio.Backends.SDL2\Ryujinx.Audio.Backends.SDL2.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Graphics.Shader\Ryujinx.Graphics.Shader.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Graphics.Nvdec\Ryujinx.Graphics.Nvdec.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Graphics.Gpu\Ryujinx.Graphics.Gpu.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Common\Ryujinx.Common.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Ui.Common\Ryujinx.Ui.Common.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Graphics.OpenGL\Ryujinx.Graphics.OpenGL.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Graphics.Texture\Ryujinx.Graphics.Texture.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\ARMeilleure\ARMeilleure.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Audio\Ryujinx.Audio.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Horizon\Ryujinx.Horizon.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Graphics.Vulkan\Ryujinx.Graphics.Vulkan.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.ShaderTools\Ryujinx.ShaderTools.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Tests\Ryujinx.Tests.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Horizon.Common\Ryujinx.Horizon.Common.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Audio.Backends.SoundIo\Ryujinx.Audio.Backends.SoundIo.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Graphics.Host1x\Ryujinx.Graphics.Host1x.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Graphics.Device\Ryujinx.Graphics.Device.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Graphics.Vic\Ryujinx.Graphics.Vic.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Memory\Ryujinx.Memory.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Ui.LocaleGenerator\Ryujinx.Ui.LocaleGenerator.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Horizon.Kernel.Generators\Ryujinx.Horizon.Kernel.Generators.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Spv.Generator\Spv.Generator.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Graphics.Video\Ryujinx.Graphics.Video.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Graphics.Nvdec.FFmpeg\Ryujinx.Graphics.Nvdec.FFmpeg.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.SDL2.Common\Ryujinx.SDL2.Common.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx\Ryujinx.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Headless.SDL2\Ryujinx.Headless.SDL2.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(678,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') [D:\Softwares\Ryujinx\src\Ryujinx.Ava\Ryujinx.Ava.csproj]
```
````

Comment: The project is https://github.com/Ryujinx/Ryujinx.git

Comment: try to delete bin and obj

Comment: The flawed language in this makes it somewhat difficult to understand

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 1):

The interruption during the compilation process might have caused some temporary files or cached data to become corrupted. The error message you're seeing is related to NuGet, which is used for package management in .NET projects. The error "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1')" typically indicates that a path is null or empty where it shouldn't be.

Here's what you can try to resolve the issue:

- Clean the Build: `dotnet clean`
- Clear NuGet Cache: `dotnet nuget locals all --clear`
- Restore NuGet Packages: `dotnet restore`

Double check the project files (especially `.csproj` files) for any corruption or misconfiguration. Sometimes manual interruptions can cause changes that affect the project structure.

Comment: I use  `dotnet nuget locals all --clear` failed, `error: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1')`. These are the same errors as question when I use `dotnet restore`.

Comment: Instead of clearing all cache locations at once, just try to clearing each cache location separately. Clear global packages cache: `dotnet nuget locals global-packages --clear`
Clear HTTP requests cache: `dotnet nuget locals http-cache --clear`
Clear temporary cache: `dotnet nuget locals temp --clear`
Use these commands one by one to see if any of them can be successfully cleared without encountering the "Value cannot be null" error.

Comment: Every command failed, the same error.

Comment: Sorry to hear that you're still facing the same error despite trying the suggested solutions. IMO, this seems to be a complex issue that might require a more in-depth investigation.

Comment: Thank you for your patient answer. In fact, I successfully built the project using Visual Studio, but I am curious about how to solve that problem. Perhaps this problem will disappear after a certain update because my package may be damaged.